# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input"}

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver

import time

import regg

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome("E:\\Nice\\chromedriver.exe") #Starting Firefox Browser
url="https://www.instagram.com/"

browser.get(url)
time.sleep

phone=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input')

phone.send_keys('0947464451')

fullname=browser.find_element_by_name("fullName")

fullname.send_keys(regg.user1)


username=browser.find_element_by_name("username")

username.send_keys (regg.user1)

password =browser.find_element_by_name("password")

password.send_keys(regg.password)

singup=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[7]/div/button").click()
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly error occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you're trying to reach the phone number input field on instagram main page.
However, the locator is working, I've checked just now. The probable reason is in page loading. There is a pre-loader on instagram website which loads page ~1-2sec.

In this case try to use *ImplicitWait* instead of sleep. Just put it right after **driver.get(url)** :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My code snippet is in Java. Interpret it to Python is not a hard thing.

Hope this will help.